# Is there a way in SharePoint to open a pdf and keep the top navigation bar frame?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I would like to be able to keep the top navigation bar on my sharepoint site and I was wondering if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try opening the PDF inside of an iFrame.  Depending on how your SharePoint site is laid out, you'll be able to control what appears on the page.